# arduino подключить библиотеку к библиотеке

Tags: c, arduino

Пробую писать свою библиотеку для ардуинки для меню LCD дисплея. Разобрался как это делается для подключения к .ino скетчу. Но мне нужно в этой библиотеке пользоваться методами *lcd.print("")* из библиотеки *LiquidCrystal_I2C*.  Никак не могу сообразить как это сделать, IDE все время ругается что метод lcd. не определен.

Помогите понять как подключить к этой библиотеке библиотеку *LiquidCrystal_I2C*.

test.ino

```
#include <LcdMenu.h>

LcdMenu menu(5);

void setup()
{
  menu.print_menu_buffer(5);
}


void loop()
{
}
```

LcdMenu.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LcdMenu.h"

LcdMenu::LcdMenu(int say_hi)
{
  _say_hi = say_hi;

};

void LcdMenu::print_menu_buffer(int menu_pos)
  {
    menu_position = menu_pos;
//lcd.clear();
//lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
//lcd.print(menu_buffer1 [menu_pos]);
  } ;
```

LcdMenu.h

```
// ensure this library description is only included once
#ifndef LcdMenu_h   
#define LcdMenu_h

#include "Arduino.h"

// library interface description
class LcdMenu {
  public:
    // constructors:
    LcdMenu(int say_hi);
    void print_menu_buffer(int menu_pos);
    void set_menu_buffer(int menu_pos, char top_line, char bottom_line);
    void get_menu_buffer(int menu_pos); 


  private:

    int _say_hi;
    int x; 
    char menu_buffer1 [1]; //{ { "top line", "bottom line" }
    char menu_buffer2 [1];
    char menu_buffer3 [1];
    char menu_buffer4 [1];
    char menu_buffer5 [1];
    char menu_buffer6 [1];
    char menu_buffer7 [1];
    char menu_buffer8 [1];
    char menu_buffer9 [1];
    char menu_buffer10 [1];
    char menu_buffer11 [1];
    char menu_buffer12 [1];
    char menu_buffer13 [1]; 

    int menu_position;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Библиотека Arduino не может вызывать функции другой библиотеки. Таково требование к библиотекам - их код должен быть самодостаточным.

Дело в том, что код скетча при компиляции копируется во временную папку, и вместе с ним копируется код библиотек, которые скетч использует. Нет способа проинформировать Arduino IDE о том, что библиотека использует другую библиотеку.

Comment: Ну а если допустим, открыть из arduino ide 1.6.8  в библиотеке DallasTemperature заголовочный файл, то в нем в 22 строке можно найти `#include <OneWire.h>` разве это не подключение библиотеки? причем если в скетче тоже подключить OneWire.h то конфликтов не будет при компиляции.

Comment: В скетче - да, а в самих библиотеках IDE не ищет подключаемые библиотеки.

Comment: Зачем тогда в заголовочном файле библиотеки объявлено подключение другой библиотеки?

Comment: Директива препроцессора #include сама по себе не есть подключение библиотеки. Это указание препроцессору включить в компиляцию данного файла ещё один файл. Чтобы не было конфликтов, возникающих из-за того, что один и тот же файл включен несколько раз, в заголовке пишут #ifndef __blabla_h_included__  и т.д.

Comment: так почему же в стандартных библиотеках это работает (значит все же есть способ) а в своей библиотеке я не могу пользоваться методами из другой библиотеки? Ведь подключение это  просто добавление в данный код другого кода.

Comment: Ну, допустим, решили Вы скачать библиотеку для своего Ардуино. Скачали, а она не компилируется. Требует какой-то заголовочный файл, которого нигде нет. Вам ведь это вряд ли понравится. Поэтому к библиотекам есть требование - они не должны использовать другие библиотеки. Чтобы Ваш скетч скомпилировался, просто добавьте в него ещё один #include.

Comment: @Vanyamba Electronics Прошу заметить что многие библиотеки на github пользуются другими готовыми билиотеками. Так что ваше заявление о том что, это не возможно, ложно.
И я так понимаю что автор вопроса хочет просто узнать способ использования методов одного класса в другом. Где и сколько раз надо написать "#include" его не волнует.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать при использовании наследования. Вот ссылка на похожий вопрос у меня. Прочитайте о **наследовании классов**.
[Arduino использовать методы одной библиотеки в другой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759559/arduino-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9/761042#761042)

**Пример из моего вопроса:**

В итоге, в файле ".ino" ну или "main.cpp" , объект будет создаваться так:

```
RF24E radio(9, 53); //для Aduino Mega2560
```

То есть, это конструктор наследника (derived class) который вызовет родителя (base class)

В файле (файл наследника) "RF24E.h" надо написать:

```
//указать что RF24E наследуется от RF24  символом ":"
 class RF24E : public RF24 //слово public разрешает вызывать (из файла ".ino") методы родителя так как будто это методы наследника
        {
          ... //здесь будут глобальные переменные наследника (они "private")
          public:
          //так как родитель имеет два типа конструктора, надо указать оба, иначе вызывается только конструктор по умолчанию (default constructor)
          //Заметьте что, тип переменных указывается лишь в наследующем конструкторе    

          //первый конструктор.
          RF24E(uint16_t _cepin, uint16_t _cspin) : RF24(_cepin, _cspin) {/*тут у 
          меня пусто*/};  

          //второй конструктор
          RF24E(uint16_t _cepin, uint16_t _cspin, uint32_t spispeed) : RF24(_cepin, 
          _cspin, spispeed) {};
         ... //тут будут методы наследника
        }
```

В основном коде, а также, внутри класса наследника, методы родителя вызываются так как-будто они являются методами наследника.