# Arduino использовать методы одной библиотеки в другой

Tags: c++, классы, arduino, библиотеки

Прошу вас объяснить или же указать на источник где можно подробно прочитать способ использования одной библиотеки Arduino в другой. 
В частности, мне надо использовать методы популярной библиотеки ["**RF24.h**"](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/). Сразу попрошу: не пишите, пожалуйста, сюда просто код, без объяснений (которых в нете просто куча). **Добавьте хотябы коментарии** ко всем его пунктам **или просто укажите на источник** где можно прочитать подробно как это делается.

Так как библиотеки Arduino - просто классы выведенные в однельные файлы с кодом, я понимаю что, мне надо, всего-то, узнать о способе использования методов одного класса в другом. Но библиотека "RF24.h" также требует несколько строк инициализации (в том числе и конструктора) перед тем как ее можно использовать. Пример:

```
RF24 radio(9, 53); //в конструктор указываем пины "ce" и "cs"
radio.begin(); // Старт работы;
radio.setChannel(0x57);
radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);  //Установка максимальной мощности;
radio.enableAckPayload();  //Разрешение отправки нетипового ответа передатчику;
radio.openReadingPipe(1, 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL); // Открываем трубу
radio.startListening();  //начинаем слушать;
```

Далее мне всего-лишь нужны методы "`radio.available()`" и "`radio.read()`"
Моя библиотека призвана помочь передавать и принимать строки символов неограниченной длины.

Добавлю что, как простой класс в основном файле ".ino" по "соседству" с библиотекой "RF24.h все отлично работает. Проблемы начинаются когда, мой класс выводится в отдельные файлы ".h" и ".cpp" и необходимо вызывать методы "RF24.h" из него. Я пробовал инициализировать "RF24.h" вот так:

```
RF24E::RF24E(uint16_t _cepin, uint16_t _cspin) //конструктор моего класса
{    
    RF24 radio(_cepin, _cspin);
    radio.begin(); // Старт работы;
    radio.setChannel(0x57);
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);  //Установка максимальной мощности;
    radio.enableAckPayload();  //Разрешение отправки нетипового ответа передатчику;
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL); // Открываем трубу
    radio.startListening();  //начинаем слушать;
};
```

**Update:** я решил перенести следующее из коменария в тело вопроса

Примеры подобно использования "библиотека в библиотеке":
[github.com/zeitgeist87/RFReceiver/blob/master/RFReceiver.h](http://github.com/zeitgeist87/RFReceiver/blob/master/RFReceiver.h) Эта библиотека основана на другой, под названием "PinChangeInterruptHandler.h" Помимо этого все библиотеки "RF24Network", "RF24Mesh" используют как фундамент библиотеку "RF24.h" Еще одна серия билиотек от "radiohead" основана на библиотеке "driver generic" и я так могу долго, но к сожалению это не помогает понять суть того как это делать самосоятельно. Я хочу полноценно осознать принцип таких пиемов, поэтому и обратился к знатокам.

Спасибо вам за потраченное время.

**Update**: Я скорее всего кажусь хамом, но все же, никто не пытается даже прочитать чего же мне действительно надо. Мне не надо лаконичных подсказок "поставь запятую - там, тирэ - здесь". Укажите, пожалуйста, на источник откуда можно это прочитать, хотябы.

P.S: в файле ".ino" объявлены обе библиотеки: "`RF24.h`" и "`RF24E.h`"

Comment: "Так как библиотеки Arduino - просто классы выведенные в однельные файлы с кодом" - разве? по мне так это (RF24) самая обычная библиотека с единицами трансляции, заголовочными файлами и линковкой.

Comment: может потому что radio создан локально в конструкторе и при выходе и конструктора его объект умирает.

Comment: "может потому что radio создан локально", я это осознал когда скомпилировал, но как сделать так чтобы можно было пользоваться ее методами,  не пойму :(

Comment: VTT - но, я использую слегка(изменил типы переменных и пару функций) измененную Arduino библиотеку на RaspberryPi и компилирую ее именно не как библиотеку, а как часть кода вынесенного в отдельные файлы...

Comment: "но как сделать так чтобы можно было пользоваться ее методами, не пойму" - Объявите RF24 radio в .h файле где вы объявляете класс RF24E.

Comment: "Объявите RF24 radio в .h файле где вы объявляете класс RF24E." Они были добавлены до того как я открыл эту тему. То есть проблема возникла уже при добавленном #include в основном файле ".ino".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден.
Нашел я его на англоязыччном форуме, вернее нашел тему которую надо прочитать - "Наследование классов".

В результате, оказывается, надо было сделать следующее:

В итоге, в файле ".ino" ну или "main.cpp" , объект будет создаваться так:

`RF24E radio(9, 53);` //для Aduino Mega2560

В файле (файл наследника) "RF24E.h" надо написать:

```
//указать что RF24E наследуется от RF24  символом ":"
 class RF24E : public RF24 //слово public разрешает вызывать (из файла ".ino") методы родителя так как будто это методы наследника
        {
          ... //здесь будут глобальные переменные наследника (они "private")
          public:
          //так как родитель имеет два типа конструктора, надо указать оба, иначе вызывается только конструктор по умолчанию (default constructor)
          //Заметьте что, тип переменных указывается лишь в наследующем конструкторе    

          //первый конструктор.
          RF24E(uint16_t _cepin, uint16_t _cspin) : RF24(_cepin, _cspin) {/*тут у 
          меня пусто*/};  

          //второй конструктор
          RF24E(uint16_t _cepin, uint16_t _cspin, uint32_t spispeed) : RF24(_cepin, 
          _cspin, spispeed) {};
         ... //тут будут методы наследника
        }
```

Спасибо еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Нет такого способа. Библиотеку использует скетч. Только скетч может использовать библиотеку.

Это ограничение связано с тем, что при компиляции скетча код библиотеки копируется во временную директорию, а саму библиотеку скрипт находит по заголовочному файлу.

Если бы библиотека могла использовать другую библиотеку, то часто возникала бы ситуация, когда одна и та же библиотека включена в скетч и в коде скетча, и в коде другой библиотеки. И мало того - это одна и та же библиотека, только разные версии.

Более того. Мы начинаем копировать код библиотек. Первая библиотека использует вторую, вторая - третью, а третья - первую. Но скетч хочет первую библиотеку одной версии, а третья библиотека хочет первую библиотеку другой версии. В итоге скетч невозможно скомпилировать, ни используя первую библиотеку первой версии, ни используя первую библиотеку второй версии.

Поэтому только скетч может использовать библиотеки.

Comment: Повторюсь что это не правда. Вот доказательства: https://github.com/zeitgeist87/RFReceiver/blob/master/RFReceiver.h Эта библиотека основана на другой, под названием "PinChangeInterruptHandler.h" Помимо этого все библиотеки "RF24Network",  "RF24Mesh" используют как фундамент библиотеку "RF24.h" Еще одна серия билиотек от "radiohead" основана на библиотеке "driver generic" и я так могу долго, но к сожалению это не помогает понять суть того как это делать самосоятельно. Я хочу полноценно осознать принцип таких пиемов, поэтому и обратился  к знатокам.

Comment: Ещё раз повторяю. Чтобы использовать библиотеку, нужно добавить инклюд в скетч.

Comment: Я его давно добавил, проблема ведь в другом. Прошу Вас, не тратьте на меня время, вы не вникаете даже в суть проблемы. Спасибо и простите.

Comment: Я объяснил логику, как это сделано и почему так. Спросите у Массимо Банзи, у него есть видео, где он объясняет этот вопрос.

Comment: Не знаю о чем там говорил Массимо, но все прекрасно работает с наследованием